# Choosing a column that fulfills many conditions in different records

Tags: mysql, select

I have got table like this:

```
+----------+---------+
| Customer | Product |
+----------+---------+
|        1 |       1 |
|        1 |       2 |
|        1 |       3 |
|        2 |       1 |
|        2 |       2 |
|        2 |       2 |
+----------+---------+
```

I would like to select Customer who bought Products 1 AND 2 AND 3. So my query should return 1. How to achieve that?

Comment: Can there be more types of product(s), other than 1,2,3 ?

Comment: Question is completely simplified to my problem, but yes it can, and lets say I get products from many subqueries

Comment: So basically two cases are possible. Case 1: Get those customers which have purchased **only 1,2,3** products and each one of them has been purchased atleast once. Case 2: Get those customers which have purchase each one of the 1,2,3 atleast (they may have purchased other products as well). Which case are you looking the solution for ?

Comment: Definitely the second solution, I need those who have at least once bought each of these products.

Comment: Ok. I have explained both the cases in my answer.

Comment: Yes, your solution is really close to my problem, but instead of SUM(Product = 1) i put subqueries over there. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `GROUP BY` on the `Customer` and use conditional aggregation based filtering inside the `Having` clause. MySQL automatically casts boolean values to 0/1 when using in numeric context.

In order to have a specific `Product` bought by a `Customer`, its `SUM(Product = ..)` should be **1**.

---

**Case 1:** Get those customers which have purchased each one of the 1,2,3 products at-least (they may have purchased other products as well).

```
SELECT Customer
FROM your_table
GROUP BY Customer
HAVING SUM(Product = 1) AND -- 1 should be bought
       SUM(Product = 2) AND -- 2 should be bought
       SUM(Product = 3)     -- 3 should be bought
```

---

If you want exclusivity, *i.e.*, the customer has not bought any other product other than 1,2,3; then you can use the following instead.

**Case 2:** Get those customers which have purchased **only** 1,2,3 products and each one of them has been purchased at-least once.

```
SELECT Customer
FROM your_table
GROUP BY Customer
HAVING SUM(Product = 1) AND  -- 1 should be bought
       SUM(Product = 2) AND  -- 2 should be bought
       SUM(Product = 3) AND  -- 3 should be bought
       NOT SUM(Product NOT IN (1,2,3))  -- anything other 1,2,3 should not be bought
```

Answer (score 4):

if you want the customer who bought all the 3 product  you could use  aggregation function `count(distinct product)`

```
    SELECT Customer
    FROM your_table
    where product in (1,2,3)
    GROUP BY Customer
    HAVING count(distinct product) = 3
```